# How to Create Separate X11 Screens in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, multiple-monitors, xorg

I need to create 2 separate X11 Screens to render two separate G-Streamer Windows.

When I type echo $DISPLAY I want to see: The first screen is :0.0, the second is :0.1 as suggested in:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead

All that is currently returned from echo $DISPLAY is :0.

I have tried editing xorg.conf to achieve this, first by disabling Xinerama in xorg.conf but that seems to have just caused a whole host of other issues not allowing me to boot into the desktop and now I will likely have to re-install Ubuntu. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to configure multiple screens in Ubuntu 16.04?

Thanks

Comment: Uhm... why do you want two separate X11 screens? Zaphod mode is quite deprecated, I think.

Comment: I need them so that I can have a G-Streamer sink element on each display. the element mfxsinkelement has a display-name property which allows a full screen hardware accelerated render on intel chips for each display. Since the dual displays are not distinct however, I can't use this as of right now. So looking for a way to make the displays distinct